# How to push element parent in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to push an nested element Mongoose.

Check the schema:

```
const Messages = new mongoose.Schema({
    /*[user]*/
    author: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Users'
      },   
      /*[room]*/
    room: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Rooms'
    },
    message_body: String,
    message_status:{type: Boolean, default: false},
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

I want to create a Message with room and Author insert, how to use that?

Comment: You mean to create the message with an already existing Author and Room? Because in that case you would only have to add their respective _id 's

Comment: @DavidVicente yes, i'm using Nosql now after Sql strucutres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you have an 'author' object and a 'room' object. These are going to be the parents. Your message object would be like this:

```
var newMessage = new Message({author: authore._id, room: room._id, message_body: messageBody ....});
newMessage.save()
.then(() => {
    /*** do more things **/
});
```

Then you will be able to use 'populate' option to make Mongoose refilling author and room fields with the whole objects.

Comment: Well if i'm using post values, i can add what?? i cannot use this method.

Comment: What do you mean with 'post values'??